# Tests are only run depending on a flag

Tags: cypress

Looking for I have an application that is used for two different customers. For most of the Tests they can be run against both customers but they both have a different splash screen.
So the idea was to pass a customer Flag so one Test only runs if Customer One Flag is sent and another Test only runs if the other customer flag is sent

How do I update the Tests for those two Test so they look at this flag? I know I could just do an if statement around the two tests but looking to see if there is a better way than this